# Runtime debugging not working.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, runtime

just recently my Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 Professional have stopped catching runtime errors. I'm not sure if a setting within these IDEs were configured wrong or if it is a firewall problem (my OS is Windows 7 and the firewall is turned off). For instance this code should result in a runtime error in visual studio:

```
XmlDocument doc = null;
XmlElement element = doc.getElementByID("element");
```

If i place a breakpoint after this code it is not reached, however the breakpoint is successfully triggering before this code sample is executed. My C# application appears fine, but all code that was executed after the error is nonexistent.

I would appreciate it if any could help me solve this issue.

Comment: are you attaching to a running process? perhaps your compiled assembly and code are out of sync.

Comment: I believe I have also experienced this. If you place a breakpoint before the exception, and then step thru, does it just exit instead of displaying the exception message? That's what happened to me, I would be interested to see the reason for this behaviour...

Comment: I was going to put this in an answer but thought it is best as a comment. What happens if you set all exceptions to break when thrown (i.e. In VS goto `Debug` -> `Exceptions` and set the exceptions to be thrown). To double check, this code isn't in a form load event event right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, this code should not even compile due to the invalid casing on GetElementById() in your example.

In Visual Studio, go to Debug -> Exceptions, check "Thrown" next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Re-run the code ... does it break?

Comment: this is really very nice option...while debugging, I found many errors like this.